# Xamarin forms dynamic resource not being used

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms

I am trying to set a specific style globally via my App.xml
however the style is not being applied to the page

here is my App.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="WTF.Framework.Applications.CrossPlatform.App">
    <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ControlTemplate x:Key="Template">
        <StackLayout>
          <Label Text="Control Template Demo App" TextColor="black" />
          <ContentPresenter />
          <BoxView Color="Teal"/>
          <Label Text="(c) WTF 2018" TextColor="Blue" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        </StackLayout>
      </ControlTemplate>
      <!--Below is how to set individual properties of components-->
      <Style x:Key="FieldLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#77787A" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="StartAndExpand" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand" />
        <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalTextAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="LineBreakMode" Value="TailTruncation" />
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
      </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

and here is my LoginPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="WTF.Framework.Presentation.CrossPlatform.Pages.Authentication.LoginPage">
  <ContentView ControlTemplate="{DynamicResource Template}">
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="5" x:Name="LoginLayout">
            <Label Text="Connection:" />
            <Picker x:Name="ConnectionPicker" SelectedItem="{Binding Connection.ConnectionName, Mode=TwoWay}" />

            <Label Text="Username:" Style="{DynamicResource FieldLabelStyle}"/>
            <Entry x:Name="UsernameEntry" Text="{Binding Username, Mode=TwoWay}" />

            <Label Text="Password:" />
            <Entry x:Name="PasswordEntry" IsPassword="True" Text="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay}" />


            <Button Text="Throw exception" x:Name="ExceptionButton" Clicked="Exception_Clicked"/>
            <Button Text="Login" x:Name="LoginButton" Clicked="LoginButton_Clicked" />
            <Button Text="Forgot Password" x:Name="ForgotPasswordButton" Clicked="ForgotPasswordButton_Clicked" />
            <Button Text="Connections" x:Name="ConnectionsButton" Clicked="ConnectionsButton_Clicked" />
            <Button Text="Server" x:Name="ServerButton" Clicked="ServerButton_Clicked" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
  </ContentView>
</ContentPage>
```

As you can see I am trying to change the Username label to be a specific style and the entire page to use the control template. However on runtime the app seems to discard the templates. Is it because the App.xaml is sitting in a different project within the same solution?

Comment: That is not a `DynamicResource` it is a `StaticResource` you should be using it like `ControlTemplate="{StaticResource Template}"`

Comment: The DynamicResource markup extension is similar to the StaticResource markup extension in that both use a dictionary key to fetch a value from a ResourceDictionary. However, while the StaticResource performs a single dictionary lookup, the DynamicResource maintains a link to the dictionary key. Therefore, if the dictionary entry associated with the key is replaced, the change is applied to the visual element. This enables runtime style changes to be made in an application.(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/dynamic) .